# Scrapy shell <url> is running all of the spiders in my 'spiders' folder

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

All I am trying to do is play around with the scrapy shell and for some reason I keep having issues where scrapy tries to un all of my spiders in succession. All I am typing is 'scrapy shell ' and it runs all of my spiders.

I really don't want to have to comment out all of my spiders just to use the shell. It's very frustrating. Any guidance would be helpful.

FYI: It also runs all of my spiders when I run "scrapy crawl " even though it should just run that particular spider.

I am running it through Anaconda using python 3.8.

Comment: when you run `scrapy shell`, are you running it from within the project folder? When you mention scrapy crawl, do you mean to say you run `scrapy crawl` on its own, or are you running `scrapy crawl myspider`?

Comment: I have tried running it in the project folder as well as in the spiders folder, and I run "scrapy crawl myspider", not just "scrapy crawl."